# Matrix integral involving trace and determinant

Tags: integration, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be symmetric positive definite matrices of dimension $(p \times p)$ and $a$, $b$ be positive reals.

I know that the following equality should hold
$$
\int_{\mathbf{A} > 0} \mathbf{A} \, \text{det}(\mathbf{A})^\frac{a - p - 1}{2}(b + \text{trace}(\mathbf{A}))^{-\frac{b+ap}{2}} d\mathbf{A} = \frac{\Gamma_p(a/2) \Gamma(b/2) b^{b/2+1} a}{\Gamma((b+ap)/2) (b-2)} \mathbf{I}.
$$

Has anyone seen this integral before and knows where I can find out more about it and related integrals?

Comment: Interesting, where does it come from?

Comment: Take a look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287794/noncentral-matrix-beta-distributions-of-type-i-and-ii#answer-287973 and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287866/integral-involving-hypergeometric-function-of-matrix-argument

Comment: A is a random matrix. Left hand side is A times kernel of pdf(A), right hand side comes from normalizing constant and expected value of the distribution.

Comment: If we consider scalar $A$ instead, then this would seem to be a variation on the usual integral representation for the beta function. As such it seems reasonable to think of this as a sort of matrix beta integral. Those do appear to have been considered historically, e.g., the preprint of Neterin at https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.2110. (I'll glance and see if that may cover your case.)

Comment: Also, what is $\Gamma_p$?

Comment: It is the multivariate gamma function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_gamma_function

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will have a look at it tomorrow.